# Crop string/html objects, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have like this

```
<%= product.technical_data.html_safe %>
```

It produces long table data. About 30 rows at least. In Product/index page I want to be able click on button, then this table shows up for just 10 first rows not for all.

And again in Product/show click on this button would open all rows in this table.
I google it found this.

```
<%= truncate(product.technical_data.html_safe, :length => 17, :separator => ' ') %>
```

But does it will work as it is html that needs crop?

**Result:**

Croped result is html code, not html_safe. How can I keep just html_safe?
Tnx

Comment: If `product.technical_data` contains HTML code, as I guess since you are using `html_safe`, it's not a good idea using `truncate` on it because it blindly truncates the text

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320160/is-there-an-html-safe-truncate-method-in-rails