# How to use truncate with link_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following along here: [Text Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html)

Specifically I'm using the last example and have in my code:

```
<%= truncate_html(posts.content) {link_to "Continue", post_path(posts.url_name)}%>
```

The first part of the truncate works but the link does not appear. Any idea why my link isn't appearing?

Comment: What is `truncate_html`? Does it accept a block? If yes, how does it use the block? Why are you using "inline" block instead of the multiline do/end one?

Comment: Ah, the docs actually suggest the inline block. First time I'm seeing this in rails. The rest of the questions still stand, though.

Comment: truncate_html isn't part of the Rails code you linked to.  Maybe you are using this: https://github.com/hgmnz/truncate_html/blob/master/lib/app/helpers/truncate_html_helper.rb and that does not take a block, so the block you provided would just be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the `truncate_html`, but you could use [this questions answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320160/is-there-an-html-safe-truncate-method-in-rails) with a block in the end:

```
<%= truncate(posts.content, :escape => false) { link_to "Continue", post_path(posts.url_name) } %>
```

That would create the result you want.

Comment: It was the escape that was getting me.

Answer (score 0):

`truncate_html` does not appear to be a valid method in the Rails base code. Try with `truncate`

```
<%= truncate(posts.content) {link_to "Continue", post_path(posts.url_name)}%>
```